# execute code every time a user moves from screen to screen in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In react I use [location](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location) as `useEffect` dependency to run some code when the browser route change.

```js
import React from "react";
import useRouter from "use-react-router";

function someComponent() {
  const {location} = useRouter();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // run some code when location change
  }, [location]);
}
```

**how to achieve this behaviour in react-native, be able to run some code when the user moves from one screen to another?** PD: I'm using react navigation

Comment: If you're using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/), then [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/)'s how you can do it

Comment: The react navigation docs point to listen this change in one specific screen, what about if I want something global like my react example, where I listen the global location object so if this object change doesn't matter in what page the user is locsted the code will be runned. How to listen `blur` event in every app screen?

Comment: If you want something similar to your React example, you can use [`useIsFocused`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/) (to determine if the screen is focused) together with [`useRoute`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-route/) (to determine specific screen params, options, its name, etc.)